# Server Is not returning response

Tags: alfresco-webscripts

I am calling a url using this code

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
                HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();
                httpCon.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                httpCon.setConnectTimeout(1200000);
                httpCon.setReadTimeout(1200000);
                httpCon.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                int responseCode = httpCon.getResponseCode();
                System.out.println(responseCode);
```

i am running a webservice in development server using local source code.the reponse is not coming back

note:-the service running time is 7-8 min.

Comment: You want to get `Response` in `JSON` by using `API Call`?

Comment: yes @user3441151 i have a api that will return json but the data is so huge so it's taking 8 mints to run i can see the service is running in server log but after finish it's not returning the values.

Comment: What you get from this API Call? Is it a JSON Array or JSON Object?

Comment: You can try my answer below.

Comment: ok thanks @user3441151

Comment: If my answer is working for you, So please accept my answer below.

Comment: Is this has been fixed?

Comment: No it's not fixed the response is not coming back.@user3441151

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139853/discussion-between-user3441151-and-sachin-singh).

Comment: Is this issue is fixed?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Imports are given below :

```
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
```

Code is given below :

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpCon.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
httpCon.setConnectTimeout(1200000);
httpCon.setReadTimeout(1200000);
httpCon.setRequestMethod("GET");
httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
int responseCode = httpCon.getResponseCode();
System.out.println(responseCode);

//For getting the response in JSON
JsonParser jp = new JsonParser();
JsonElement root = jp.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) httpCon.getContent()));
JsonObject innerRootobj = root.getAsJsonObject();
System.out.println("innerRootobj : " + innerRootobj);
```